# How to run code synchronously using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronization

ajax `sync` keyword can be used to pause to code.
async:false = Code paused.
async:true = Code continued.
This is a function I am experimenting with.

```
function ajax_async(){
    var paused = false;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST", 
        async: false,
        data: content,
        url: ajax_url,
        success:function(data){
            paused = true;  // ajax_async() will return true. Without this it will return false.
            $.confirm({scrollToPreviousElement: false,
                scrollToPreviousElementAnimate: false, 
                title: '...',
                async: false, // This attempt does not work.
                content: data,
                buttons: {
                    confirm: function () {
                        // This value is not considered
                        paused = true;
                    }                        
                },
                cancel: function () {
                    //close
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return paused;
}
```

In my case, it's just a question of pausing the code before the confirmation section, and the `paused` variable is returned before this section.
The problem seems to be with `$.confirm(...`.
The `paused` value is returned before the `$.confirm({`) block is executed. Using `async: false` here does not solve the problem.
How can I pause all the code, and only return the value of `paused` at the end of the program's execution?

Comment: `$.confirm` by the name will show a confirmation dialog popup - this is not an `AJAX` process, so `async` doesn't apply here.

Comment: You need to change your thinking around browser/user interactions.  It appears you're trying to "pause" some code while your ajax+confirm are running - no doubt to "continue" with some code later - that "continue" code should be initiated from the `confirm:` callback of the `$.confirm`

Comment: Attempting to pause code execution like this also freezes the UI thread, meaning your page becomes unresponsive and users can't click buttons and interact with the page so I doubt you can really have a synchronous click event work like this as your page will be essentially "frozen"/"stuck".

Comment: Thanks you for your replies. I'm going to change the way I approach the problem.

Comment: I'd call the function something other than `ajax_async` ... since clearly it's not

Comment: FYI: For some time, `async: false` has been frowned-upon as it locks up the browser (as noted above) so the user can't do anything at all in that browser (used to lock the *entire window* (before tabs) so you couldn't even move/min the window!  erk).   If you run your code in latest Chrome, it states that `async: false` is deprecated and may/will be removed in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The ideal solution would be to already find an alternative solution that doesn't use `async: false`.